# Using Yaml file as a simple script record

Tags: json, yaml

I'm trying to create a simple way to make scripts to execute some tasks one by one - something similar to Gcodes in CNC machines.
On first fire I get YAML and I'm trying to create a schema that allows me to create multiple very similar (or identical) lines, but I bounced off the wall. With the in YAML, every object should be unique. How I should prepare the schema? Is it possible to repeat these objects?

For reading, I use the `cpp-yaml` lib.

This is an example of my YAML:

```
Drawer:
  uid: W1
  cmd: out

Drawer:
  uid: W2
  cmd: in

Heater:
  id: H1
  duty: 5
  temp: 4
  time: 2

Heater:
  id: H2
  duty: 1
  temp: 33
  time: 15
```

As a schema.json I tried both the following configurations:

```
"properties": {
    "Heater": {
```

and

```
"definitions": {
   "Acctuator": {
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the tasks to be executed one by one, a mapping is the wrong data structure. YAML specifically defines that the order of mapping keys is a presentation detail and must not convey content information. So if you want the tasks to be executed in a specific order, use a sequence:

```
- !Drawer
  uid: W1
  cmd: out

- !Drawer
  uid: W2
  cmd: in

- !Heater
  id: H1
  duty: 5
  temp: 4
  time: 2

- !Heater
  id: H2
  duty: 1
  temp: 33
  time: 15
```

I used YAML tags for specifying the type of task, which is how YAML distinguishes between different data types. You could instead use an embedded mapping in each sequence item, e.g.:

```
- Drawer:
    uid: W1
    cmd: out
```

If you want to use JSON Schema to describe your file's content, you can't use YAML tags because they are not a JSON feature. However afaik the only implementation of JSON Schema that works on YAML files is in JavaScript, so you can't really use it in C++ anyway.